# Creating a dynamic named range in Excel

Tags: excel, named-ranges

I'am trying to create a named range to use as part of a data validation drop down menu.  I'm creating this from a table, however, I only want to display the values from Column A which meet a certain criteria(true or false) in Column C.  However, the values in Column C can change so I need the named range to be able to change as well.

My table looks like this:

```
    A    B    C
    1    ..   1
    2    ..   0
    3    ..   1
    4    ..   0
    5    ..   1
    6    ..   1
```

I would like the named range to pick the values for A where c is 1 - or in this example 1,3,5,6.

Comment: `I would like the named range to pick the values for A where c is 1 - or in this example 1,3,5,6.` And I would like to see what have you tried till now and where are you stuck? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I have tried using various methods I have found on here, and on the internet in general, as well as a solution that involved a pivot table.  However, this was not ideal as it required refreshing the pivot table and named range when data changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with a helper column:

In D2 enter

```
=IF(C2,ROW(),"")
```

Copy down. Create a list of values in column F, starting in F2 with

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(D:D,ROW(A1))),"")
```

Copy down. 
Create a named range that refers to the formula

```
=Sheet1!$F$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$F:$F,MATCH(99^99,Sheet1!$F:$F,1))
```

Use that range name in the data validation list value.

When a value in column C changes from 0 to 1 or vice versa, the validation list will update immediately.

[image]

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained Ingeborg :)